# MPAndroidChart, what is the relationship between MPChartExample and MPChartLib?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

First, I add a dependency(MP) to my project likes official instructions in my own project but I cannot import `com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample.custom.MyMarkerView`. I find `MarkerView.java` is located in `MPChartLib`. So, I want to know what is the relationship between `MPChartLib` and `MPChartExample`? thanks.
[Project Structure Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F90J.png)

Comment: MpChartLib is the full Library and MpChartExample is created for examples that how we can add this library in our Application.

Comment: got it, thanks. And i want know why i can't find MarkerView in MpChartExample,  where is it? Beacause i find XYMarkerView.class and MyMarkerView.class extends MarkerView. but i can only find MarkerView in MpChartLib.